# Automatically move forward to what is really live on a Youtube livestream after a pause and resume

Tags: youtube-live

When I watch a Youtube livestream, and then I pause it, and then continue it after a while, it just continues from where it left off. So this makes me watch stuff that has happened before, and I am not really seeing what is live. Can I change any setting so that I can automatically move forward to what is really live on the livestream when I resume the pause?

EDIT:
Oh I just found out the LIVE button does this. However, is there a keyboard key that does this (instead of having to click on it)?

Answer (score 1):

You can press the <kbd>END</kbd> key or hold down <kbd>></kbd> until what you see is live.

[image]